# Android TextView, autoLink="all" showing all numbers as clickable

Tags: android, textview

I have a Scrollview and I have the attribute `android:clickable="true"` and `android:autoLink="all"`.

I have a string for the ScrollView, and the emails, tel numbers etc, appear and are correctly clickable.

However, The string contains other numbers, such as Years, which also appear clickable and I don't want this; how can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `autoLink="all"`, use the [ones you need](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink).

`android:autoLink="web|email|phone"` will probably cover your use cases.

The `clickable="true"` on the `ScrollView` isn't needed for this; rather you should set the `autoLink` attribute on the `TextViews` themselves; perhaps extracting a style if you have other common properties.

---

Add the new [Linkify](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/430fc97/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java) class to your project. From a place that you have access to the TextView (e.g. the Activity):

```
TextView myTextView = // get a reference to your textview
int mask = Linkify.ALL;
Linkify.addLinks(myTextView, mask);
```

The `addLinks(TextView, int)` method is static, so you can use it without creating an instance of `Linkify`. The return value (`boolean`) indicates whether something was linkified, but you probably don't need this information, so we don't bother with it.

You'll need to ensure that you don't put the `autoLink` attribute on the `TextViews`, otherwise the `setText(...)` implementations will still linkify years (unless you completely override the `setText(...)` implementations without calling `super.setText(...)`)

---

For extra brownie points, you can create a subclass of `TextView` which will do the linkify for you when you set text on it:

```
public class AutoLinkifyTextView extends TextView {

    public AutoLinkifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoLinkifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        super.setText(text);
        parseLinks();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(int stringRes) {
        super.setText(stringRes);
        parseLinks();
    }

    private void parseLinks() {
        Linkify.addLinks(this, Linkify.ALL);
    }

}
```

For top marks of course, you'd read the attributes from the `attrs` and use the correct mask from the XML attributes, but I'd prefer to get rid of that option and do it here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ataulm. The TextView is within the ScrollView, sorry that was not clear from my question. I have tried what you suggest, but years (4 digits)still appear as clickable, and if I click on a year, I get the choice of using the phone.

Comment: Looks like [a bug](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/430fc97) in the Linkify source. You can either drop the autolink for phone, or copy the new Linkify class into your project and use it manually with `Linkify.addLinks(TextView, int)`

Comment: Hi @ataulm, I have taken the "phone" from autolink from where there are no phone numbers, and that works. BUT if there are telephone numbers in the string, and I want phones to be clickable, Years appear clickable too. Sorry, have just seen your comment. Will do what you suggest and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi ataulm, silly question, but do I just add: public static final boolean addLinks (TextView text, int mask) {
  return false;
 } to the Java Class like above?

Comment: @user3079872 na, you don't have to add a method - you use one that is already defined in the Linkify class that you copy/paste into your project. I've added a basic example, and an alternative (of which I prefer the second)